# How to know a specific launchd .plist file location?

Tags: macos, launchd, launch-daemon, launch-agent

Is it possible to know the .plist file location which is loaded by the `launchctl` command?

The label name is listed with `launchctl list` and its contents can be viewed by `launchctl list LABEL`, but I cannot find the .plist file location.

I know it will be located in `/Library/LaunchAgent` or `~/Library/LaunchAgent` or somewhere,
but I don't want to search around paths for all jobs listed by the `launchctl` command.

Comment: Thank you trojanfoe, i didn't know about the site!

Answer (score 23):

As of macOS 10.12.6 (not sure about earlier versions) it is possible to invoke: `launchctl dumpstate` and you will get a wealth of information about all running processes

Look for `<LABEL> = {` as the first line of info pertaining to that job

Here's a one liner to get all the active daemons and their plist paths:

`grep -B 1 -A 4 "active count = 1$" <<< "$(launchctl dumpstate)"`

Update: Since 10.12 macOS has added other values so the grep `-A n` has been increased to 4 lines

Comment: On my machine anyway this doesn't work.  It only gives a partial dump then just stops with no error message or anything in the middle of a random service after exactly 20mb of data

Comment: @None: the followup question you asked [launchctl dumpstate won't give full dump](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/425542/launchctl-dumpstate-wont-give-full-dump)

Comment: @JoelBruner: `launchctl dumpstate` is very useful; note it's an undocumented subcommand of `launchctl`, not even listed under "LEGACY SUBCOMMANDS"

Answer (score 16):

This issue comes up a lot and unfortunately `locate` and `mdfind` both don't show results from the appropriate directories on my system. I put the following function in my `.bashrc` so I could quickly search the directories where launchctl looks for plist files.

```
launchctlFind () {
    LaunchctlPATHS=( \
        ~/Library/LaunchAgents \
        /Library/LaunchAgents \
        /Library/LaunchDaemons \
        /System/Library/LaunchAgents \
        /System/Library/LaunchDaemons \
    )

    for curPATH in "${LaunchctlPATHS[@]}"
    do
        grep -r "$curPATH" -e "$1"
    done
    return 0;
}
```

Note that this only checks in the directories where `launchctl` looks for files at boot-up and login. It may not find everything because jobs can be manually loaded by the user and/or other processes.

UPDATE: For those running macOS 10.12.6 or higher I would recommend using  Joel Bruner's solution.

Comment: It's better to change "grep -r " to "grep -R" to let the grep command follow symlinks.

Answer (score 6):

This question might have has no answer! It seems that not everything in `launchctl list` will have a plist file at all.

As mentioned, `launchctl dumpstate` will give you tons of info on things including the plist path, if it exists.

You can run this command to approximately see a list of everything running and its plist path.

```
launchctl dumpstate | grep -A4 " = {" | grep -B 3 -A 3 -E "active count = [1-9]"
```

(Though this also seems to include other programs running that aren't daemons managed by launchd?)

The agents/daemons will have a path field underneath their identifier.  Usually, the paths point to a plist file in the standard 5 locations described by [Reed's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28907800/142318). However, it doesn't have to be.  For example Steam loads a launchctl service from a nonstandard location.

```
➜ launchctl dumpstate | grep -A4 " = {" | grep -B 3 -A 3 -E "active count = [1-9]"  | grep valve
com.valvesoftware.steam.ipctool = {
    path = /Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Steam/com.valvesoftware.steam.ipctool.plist
```

Fortunately that practice isn't too popular so searching the standard locations is usually sufficient.

But that's not the trickiest thing. I don't know the specifics but it appears that `launchctl` services can be loaded without a corresponding plist file at all. For example, this is what dumpstate says for the 1Password helper daemon.

```
➜ launchctl dumpstate | grep -A4 " = {" | grep -B 3 -A 3 -E "active count = [1-9]"  | grep -A4 "onepassword7-helper = {"
2BUA8C4S2C.com.agilebits.onepassword7-helper = {
    active count = 5
    path = (submitted by smd.1154)
    state = running
```

I don't know what "submitted by smd" really means, but it boils down to even if I see a helper in `launchctl list` there might not be any plist on the filesystem. Because of this I don't know how to `launchctl unload` this service because unload requires a plist path!  And since this process is managed by `launchd`, even if I `pkill -9 onepassword7-helper`, `launchd` sees that the process stopped and starts it right back up again.

(fortunately for this particular 1Password example, if you hold `^` and `⌥` when clicking Quit 1Password, a special "Quite 1Password Completely" option will appear)

Comment: Funny side note, but I've been using `grep` for years and wasn't aware of the `-B` and `-A` flags until I just read this post. This is tremendously useful. Thanks!

Comment: @Geoff looking back on it now, my use of `-B 3 -A 3` should really just be `-C 3`, since that's the same thing :-D

Answer (score 6):

In recent versions of macOS you can use the `launchctl print` command.  You have to know which domain it's running under, e.g. `system` or `gui/<uid>`.  There are a few other domains you can find in the man page, but so far I have only seen services running under these two.  Examples:

```
% launchctl print gui/$(id -u)/com.apple.cloudphotod  | grep path
    path = /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.cloudphotod.plist

 % launchctl print system/com.openssh.sshd | grep path 
    path = /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
    stderr path = /dev/null
```

I believe this command was implemented in High Sierra or thereabouts.

Answer (score 4):

The process name used in `launchctl list` is declared in a plist. While the plist should be at the location mentioned above, they can be almost anywhere.

I found the plist i was looking for with' locate. I was looking for org.postgresql.postgres
    `locate *.plist | grep org.postgresql.postgres`
narrowed it down to 4 files

Answer (score 3):

Here is the command to list all loaded `.plist` files and their corresponding files:

> `find /System/Library/Launch* /Library/Launch* ~/Library/Launch* -name '*.plist' -exec sh -c '/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print Label" {} && echo {}' ';' | grep -wf <(launchctl list | grep -o "\S\+\..*$") -A1 | strings`

or another version:

> `find /System/Library/Launch* /Library/Launch* ~/Library/Launch* -name '*.plist' -exec /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print Label" {} ';' -print | grep -wf <(launchctl list | grep -o "\S\+\..*$") -A1 | strings`

Explanation:

- `find` all `.plist` files in the following locations: `/System/Library/Launch*` `/Library/Launch*` `~/Library/Launch*`
- Use `PlistBuddy` command to print `Label` of all found `.plist` files.
- Use `-print` parameter of `find` to print the path to that file.
- Fetch another list of all the jobs loaded into `launchd` and use as pattern file for `grep -f`.
- Filter both lists and find the common elements and print its label along with its path (`-A1`).
- Filter via `strings` to avoid printing binary files.

Comment: Note that plists can be loaded into launchctl that aren't in any of those default locations.  Steam and 1Password do this.  So this won't find everything.

Answer (score 2):

Since `launchctl list` list PIDs, one method is to use `lsof` command to see all loaded files of the process, e.g.

```
launchctl list | grep -o '^[0-9]\+' | xargs -n1 lsof -p | grep plist$
```

---

Another way is to run `fs_usage` command and re-load the `.plist` file, e.g.

```
sudo fs_usage | grep -w launchd | grep -w plist
```

Comment: On at least Catalina, the plist is not left open by the launched process, so this solution does not work. Unfortunately. Great idea though

Answer (score 0):

On Catalina, I devised this script to print out the plist of all regex-matching objects found in the `system` domain or logged-in users. Please note, this is a BASH script, but also worked in my ZSH test.

Usage: `find_loaded_plist [ regex ]`

Please report bugs/suggestions in the comments below.

```
find_loaded_plist() {
     launchctl list  | 
     awk "NR>1 && /${1:-^}/  { print \$3 }"  | 
     while read name; do
             launchctl print system/$name 2>/dev/null | 
                sed -n 's/^[[:space:]]*path = //p'
             for u in $(users |xargs id -u ) ; do                                 
                  launchctl print uid/$u/$name 2>/dev/null |
                     sed -n 's/^[[:space:]]*path = //p'
             done;
     done; 
}
```