# List All Loaded/Unloaded or Both Launch Agents On macOS

Tags: macos, launchctl, launch-agent

I am trying to figure out how many launch agents are loaded right now using following command the it

```
find /System/Library/Launch* /Library/Launch* ~/Library/Launch* -name '*.plist' -exec sh -c '/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print Label" {} && echo {}' ';' | grep -wf <(launchctl list | grep -o "\S\+\..*$") -A1

grep -B 1 -A 1 "active count = 1$" <<< "$(launchctl dumpstate)"
```

but its not listed the one I am looking for.
is it correct?

Answer (score 10):

Using [launchctl](https://ss64.com/osx/launchctl.html) you can list all the *running* agents and daemons like such:

```
launchctl list
```

and

```
sudo launchctl list
```

please note that the two are different commands.
Oddly enough, running `sudo launchutil list` prints out the root daemons, and **only** the root deamons.

If you are running the commands in the terminal you will want to run the non-sudo version first, because if you don't, the sudo version will create a root session which will force version #1 to have root privileges anyways!

If you would like to find the file path to such an agent or daemon, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18502705/11161266)
may help.

### Edit:

Okay, I don't know how I missed the word "unloaded" in the giant title in your question but... here are the directories that daemons/agents like to hide in (copied from the man page of launchctl):

```
FILES
 ~/Library/LaunchAgents         Per-user agents provided by the user.
 /Library/LaunchAgents          Per-user agents provided by the administrator.
 /Library/LaunchDaemons         System wide daemons provided by the administrator.
 /System/Library/LaunchAgents   OS X Per-user agents.
 /System/Library/LaunchDaemons  OS X System wide daemons.
```

Comment: Running the non-sudo version BEFORE of the sudoed version is CRUCIAL. If not invoked in this order, you don't get your non-sudoed ones. I was turning crazy, and managed to list the one I was looking for once I was aware of this.

Comment: It might be useful to add `| grep -v com.apple` to hide system entries.

Answer (score 0):

I had your same question and [this article was super helpful](https://www.sentinelone.com/blog/how-malware-persists-on-macos/). I suggest reading through it, but here's a relevant snippet:

> While it’s not a simple matter for users to enumerate all the Login Items, admins can do so with a little extra work by parsing the following file, if it exists: ~/Library/ApplicationSupport/com.apple.backgroundtaskmanagementagent/backgrounditems.btm

Parsing that file is more complicated than opening it with your favorite editor. The article links to a paste bin, but this [github repo](https://github.com/mnrkbys/bgiparser) is a one-stop shop. Still, the article will help a lot.