# Name, PID, of application that invoked shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sh, pid

Let’s say we have an app called qBittorrent that allows us to run a shell script upon completion of a torrent download. While writing that shell script, to be invoked by qBittorrent, we realize it would be handy to have the PID of the app that called the shell script - in this case qBittorrent.

How do I achieve this in bash, zsh or sh?

I have read a few hints here and come across `$PPID`. On macOS this gives me `etc/launchd` not qBittorrent. It could be that qBittorrent is calling `etc/launchd` to run the shell script…

in that case would I need to return a list of parent processes and how could I achieve this?

Tried:

`ps $PPID -o comm= >> /Users/john/Desktop/log.txt 2>&1`

Returns:

```
/sbin/launchd
```

`ps -o comm= >> /Users/john/Desktop/log.txt 2>&1`

Returns:

```
/bin/zsh
-zsh
-zsh
-zsh
-zsh
```

I happen to have four terminal windows active when this script ran.

Comment: What exactly works depends on your OS. In very brief, you can parse the output of `ps´ to traverse the parent PID links in the generated output, but the precise formatting and what options to use is widely system-dependent.

Comment: I don't have qBitTorrent, but the symptoms you describe sound like qBitTorrent uses `launchd` specifically to detach itself from the process it asks `launchd` to launch, probably so the parent can exit and leave the (pseudo-) child running indefinitely under the LaunchD daemon and not worry about waiting for it etc.

Comment: There might be an option to `launchctl` which allows you to search for what started a particular job but this is outside of my expertise. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56573815/list-all-loaded-unloaded-or-both-launch-agents-on-macos looks vaguely like a useful starting point.

Comment: @tripleee I modified the question after attempts with `ps`

Comment: That doesn't change the basic problem. If qBitTorrent doesn't directly start a child, but asks LaunchD to start a child, the child process will not have a useful parent PID, and you need a different mechanism to support your use case.